# ruby array checking for nil array

Tags: ruby, arrays, null

I have ruby array and it is `nil` but when I check using `nil?` and `blank?` it returns `false`

```
@a = [""]

@a.nil?
=> false

@a.empty?
=> false
```

How do I check for the nil condition that return true?

Comment: `[""]` is _not_ nil. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I get the [""] array if this array is coming then it should not go to inner part of the block.

Comment: Just do `if @a == [""]`?

Comment: If it is an array, then it is not `nil`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`[""]` is an array with a single element containing an empty String object. `[].empty?` will return `true`. `@a.nil?` is returning `false` because `@a` is an Array object, not `nil`.

Examples:

```
"".nil? # => false
[].nil? # => false
[""].empty? # => false
[].empty? # => true
[""].all? {|x| x.nil?} # => false
[].all? {|x| x.nil?} # => true
[].all? {|x| x.is_a? Float} # => true
# An even more Rubyish solution
[].all? &:nil? # => true
```

That last line demonstrates that `[].all?` will *always* return true, because if an Array is empty then by definition all of its elements (no elements) fulfill every condition.

Answer (score 14):

In ruby, you can check like this

```
[""].all? {|i| i.nil? or i == ""}
```

If you are on rails, you could do

```
[""].all? &:blank?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p defined? "" #=> "expression"
p defined? nil #=> "nil"
```

The one `""` you are thinking as `nil`, actually an `expression`. Look at the size of an `empty` array and `non-empty` array as below for more proof:

```
p [].size #=> 0
p [""].size #=> 1
```

Said the your `#nil?` and `#empty` gives `false`. Which is expected.